# How to delete the last item of WinJS Group Binding List

Tags: javascript, list, windows-8, binding, winjs

I am writing a Windows 8 app with WinJS. I am using a Grouped Binding List

```
var groupedSortedListProjection = list.createGrouped(groupKey, groupData, groupSorter);
```

that will have two groups with keys of 'doing' and 'done'. So, when a user click on an item in group 'doing', an item will be added to 'done'.

I am trying to limit the number of items in group 'done' to only 5 items. So every time a new item is added to group 'done', the last (oldest) item will be deleted. I need an index to do that. However, I do not know how to get to the index for the last item.

What's more, I found this method in MSDN:

```
List.lastIndexOf
```

The example is:

```
var number = list.lastIndexOf(searchElement, fromIndex);
```

I think this is the answer but I have no idea how to use this method.

This is my HTML code for the ListView:

```
<div class="appViewContentMask">
        <div class="appViewContent">
            <div id="gridViewToDo" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{
 itemTemplate:select('#toDoTemplate'),
 groupHeaderTemplate: select('#headerTemplate'),
 layout:{type:WinJS.UI.GridLayout},
 itemsDraggable : true,
 itemsReorderable : true}"></div>

        </div>
</div>
```

I wire up the data with Javascript:

Thank you for reading. I hope my question is clear enough. If you need more information, tell me and I will post more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to be able to delete the oldest finished task is to add `finishTime` into the item and have it part of the sorting key . That way - the oldest item can be found at the end of the list. Sorting based on this key needs to be done in the [createSorted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700743.aspx) projection.

Thereafter [createGrouped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700742.aspx) projection needs to be used to group the items and order the groups.

The item is to be modified and removed in the [iteminvoked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211827.aspx) handler.

For full details and code listing, refer [here](http://blog.programtheeworld.com/2013/12/03/using-winjs-binding-list-to-update-the-list-view/).

Comment: Sry, I kind of click 'enter' and it posted before I finished.
Hi Sushil, thank you for your post. Your code block is clever. I did not know a whole bunch. Like how you use 'selectionMode' to disable right click. 
However, I kind of ran into an issue with oniteminvoked function. The way you wrote it, when an user click on an item in 'done' group, it will still be invoked and the last item will be deleted. So I added if(item.status == 'todo){} to only invoke 'todo' items. Do you know a way to actually improve it? Thanks!

Comment: this looks ok since click on 'done' items should be a noop. updated code in the post as per this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the splice method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700810.aspx) on the List which operates like that of an array. Once you find the index of the item you would like to remove you simply say:

```
groupedSortedListProjection.splice(index, 1);
```

In order to find the index you can ask the group, or in your case since you know the 'done' group is second and is the last group in the collection then the last element in that group will also conveniently be the last item in the collection, do your code is:

```
var index = groupedSortedListProjection.length - 1;
groupedSortedListProjection.splice(index, 1);
```

However, if it you didn't have that invariant and had to instead find the right group the code would look something like:

```
var groups = groupedSortedListProjection.groups;
var group = {}; // start with an empty object to make the for loop condition simpler
for (var i = 0; i < groups.length && group.key !== "done"; i++) {
  group = groups.getItemAt(i);
}
var index = group.firstItemIndexHint + group.groupSize - 1;
groupedSortedListProjection.splice(index, 1);
```

Hope that helps.

-josh

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.
I tried your method:
'groupedSortedListProjection.splice(index, 1);'
However, it did not work. The last item of my 'done' group often have an index of '0' or '1' and increasing. With the length of 'done' group increasing when a new task is done while the index of the last item does not so it did not work.
Another question, you know how how the indexing works for Binding.list, like when a new item is added, does it change the index of every single item or just the newly added? I checked it out but I did not really understand it. Thank you :)